# Не пойму, как пользоваться командой Preview в программе LyX

Tags: lyx

В меню **Вставка** есть команда ***Preview***. Для чего она нужна, как ей пользоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю. Я ее понял в числе последних. Математический, `Ctrl`+`M`, (или выклочный, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`M`) режим имеет, с одной стороны, преимущество в том, что вводимая формула отображается сразу в том виде, в каком она будет отображаться в конечном файле, но, с другой стороны, он имеет 2 недостатка, а именно: невозможность, вообще говоря, правки уже введенной формулы (например, если в формуле в математическом режиме использовалась команда \textcolor (как это делается, я расскажу в другой раз), то после закрытия и повторного открытия файла .lyx становится невозможным изменить цвет текста) и отчасти неправильная интерпретация символа "\" (2 знака backslash) или "&". Понимаете, в процессе экспорта или предпросмотра, например, в pdflatex, файл .lyx, с которым сейчас работаешь, порождает соответствующий файл .tex (этот файл, как и файлы, обычно образующиеся при обработке pdflatex.exe какого-нибудь файла .tex в каком-нибудь ["настоящем" редакторе LaTeX](http://mydebianblog.blogspot.com/2013/02/latex-editors-and-integrated-latex.html) 
помещается в папку, указанную в **Инструменты>Настройки>Пути** в текстовом поле ***Временный каталог***), который и подвергается обработке установленного на компе ТеХ'а. Так вот, то, что я пишу в математическом режиме в LyX, может, вообще говоря, отличаться от того, что запишется в соответствующий файл `.tex`. То, что запишется в соответствующий файл `.tex`, к примеру, в формулах, видно, если нажать **Вид>Просмотреть исходный текст**, при этом в основном окне LyX появляется область *Исходный текст LaTeX* (а, может, и отдельно от основного окна: если мы до этого эту область вытащили мышкой из основного окна LyX). Так вот, как видно в этой области, когда мы в математическом режиме вводим "\\", например, для начала новой строки матрицы, LyX воспринимает это как "\backslash\backslash", а "&" в математическом режиме воспринимается как "\&":

[image]

(если после `\begin`
 я просто нажму `Shift`+`{`, то в понимании LyX это будет означать ввод `∖{`, что не является верным - правильно надо вводить `\`+`Shift`+`{`). С одной стороны, в случае матрицы с обыкновенными разделителями на всю высоту матрицы неправильное понимание символов "\\" и "&" легко преодолимо с помощью команды ***Матрица***, расположенной на панели инструментов "Формула (автоматически)". С другой стороны, упомянутой командой ***Матрица*** не введешь макет матрицы с разделителями деления уголком

```
∖∖arraycolsep=0.05em
∖∖begin{array}{rrr@{∖,}r|r}
x^2&{}+2x&{}-12&&∖∖,x+5∖∖\∖
∖∖cline{5-5}
x^2&{}+5x&&&∖∖,x-3∖∖∖∖
∖∖cline{1-2}
&{}-3x&{}-12∖∖∖∖
&{}-3x&{}-15∖∖∖∖
∖∖cline{2-3}
&&3
∖∖end{array}
```

(пример кода взят из книги С. М. Львовского "Набор и верстка...", стр. 223): попытка вставить преамбулу матрицы приведенного кода в текстовое поле ***Горизонтально*** диалогового окна "LyX: Матрица", открывающегося после нажатия упомянутой команды Матрица, дает совсем не тот результат. Все это, на первый взгляд, свидетельствует о некоторой ущербности LyX. А на самом деле это не так. Нет, может, эта ущербность и есть, только мне не хватило фантазии ее выявить. Ну, и вот. Нажимаем **Вставка>Preview**, нажимаем в появившемся прямоугольнике команду **Вставить код ТеХ** (ту, что выполняется сочетанием клавиш `Ctrl`+`l`) и вот в эту конструкцию мы и вставляем приведенный выше код. Все, выводим курсор из прямоугольника, созданного описываемой в этой теме командой. После некоторого времени, 1-2 секунды, без экспорта и предпросмотра, мы видим то, что получится из этого кода в конечном файле выхода, но только видим мы это в окне LyX. Это все применимо не только к объектам LaTeX, но и к графике, генерируемой tikz и pstricks (при подключении соответствующих пакетов). Например, следующий [файл .lyx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SPULmuiKy5tErdNtAy82HeyDEvSCUt7/view?usp=sharing) в открытом виде выглядит следующим образом:

[image]

Внизу, кстати, видна панель *буфер команды*, которая предоставляет, в частности, еще один способ решения проблемы неправильной интерпретации "\" и "\&". Как ей пользоваться, рассказано здесь.